# Tomcat web apps location question

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am q java web apps developer.
I am using Eclipse+Tomcat.
Currently I am working on about 10 web apps.

Here is my problem:
My web apps are not all placed under a single folder, they are located in different places.

To test my changes I have to export my web apps into war files or to move the updated files manually every time so the Tomcat will recognize them.

This seems like a waste of time for me.

Is there a way to tell tomcat where my web apps located instead of copying files every time?

Comment: Are you running Tomcat from within Eclipse or standalone?

Comment: Standalone, but it won't help if I'll run it from within Eclipse because my web-apps are not considered web-apps by eclipse. The maven builds the web-app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using [Eclipse Webtools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)?
If you're not, consider doing so. You will be able to configure Eclipse to launch Tomcat with your web applications, have them auto-reloaded, etc...

Short of that, you could still configure your Tomcat server to pick up your web applications from wherever you want by specifying appropriate document base in either `server.xml` or your webapp's `context.xml`

Here's a link to [Server Tools documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/topic/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/cwover.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a tutorial telling you how tomcat and eclipse are supposed to work together to forge a development environment.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html

Follow it and you will not be exporting the .war all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with Tomcat. For each app you want run from somewhere else, you need to place a context fragment in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/[host] directory. For example,

```
app1.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/anywhere/app1" swallowOutput="true">
</Context>
```

The xml file name will be your context name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). It will solve this problems

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to use Tomcat to test your apps... You can use the **[Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/)** web server from within Eclipse, which is very comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should load your application from context files rather than the server.xml. There is no need to load a application every time in the container. You can run your application from the place where it is.
Please use this [link](http://www.chemaxon.com/jchem/doc/admin/tomcat.html)